# how to set "company" information in file properties through cygwin

Tags: cygwin

After I right-click on a file in Windows, a pop-up menu appears with "Properties" on its bottom.

Going to: Mouse-Right-Click on a File -> Properties -> Details I get a tab with file description containing:

File Description,
Type,
File Version,
Product Version,
Copyright,
Size,
Date modified,
Language.

Is it possible to setup any of the above parameters (Example: File Version, Product Version, Copyright) from cygwin? I want to have the parameters available after each compile/build session.

If yes please let me know, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small guidance on Cygwin user guide at
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/windres.html

For example the Cygwin1.dll info are stored in:

https://cygwin.com/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/winver.rc;h=980d51204c84b67d09c9cb1e247cc899a72ea288;hb=HEAD

```
  27 BEGIN
  28   BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  29   BEGIN
  30     BLOCK "040904B0"
  31     BEGIN
  32       VALUE "CompanyName", "Red Hat"
  33       VALUE "FileDescription", "Cygwin POSIX Emulation DLL"
  34       VALUE "FileVersion", STRINGIFY(CYGWIN_VERSION)
  35       VALUE "InternalName", CYGWIN_DLL_NAME
  36       VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright \251 Cygwin Authors 1996-" STRINGIFY(CYGWIN_BUILD_YEAR)
  37       VALUE "OriginalFilename", CYGWIN_DLL_NAME
  38       VALUE "ProductName", "Cygwin"
  39       VALUE "ProductVersion", STRINGIFY(CYGWIN_VERSION)
  40       VALUE "APIVersion", CYGWIN_API_VERSION
  41       VALUE "SharedMemoryVersion", STRINGIFY(CYGWIN_VERSION_SHARED_DATA)
  42       VALUE "RegistryKey", CYGWIN_INFO_CYGWIN_REGISTRY_NAME
  43       VALUE "BuildDate", CYGWIN_BUILD_DATE_TIME
  44     END
  45   END
  46   BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  47   BEGIN
  48       VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
  49   END
  50 END
```